# Image not appearing. Instead it is displaying the alt text

Tags: html, pgadmin

I think this may be my first time posting on Stack Overflow instead of just browsing for already-answered questions.

I am not an avid html user and I am trying to update our splash page for our web app through pgadmin.

I know PostgreSQL has a weird quirk of where it starts to look for things. I believe it currently is rooted in a temp directory that is recreated each time the app starts which isn't ideal for storing a picture for its splash screen so I put the picture in the public pictures directory (C:\Users\Public\Pictures\download.jpg). but using  or  didn't work I only see the alt text.

So I thought that was maybe because it was starting in this weird directory so I tried doing  to go back to C root and go from there but still not working. Has anybody experienced something like this? It can't be that difficult!

Update with code:

```html
<img src=C:\Users\Public\Pictures\download.jpg alt="CMB Logo" height=300>
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, please provide a simpliefied code which reproduced your problem.

Comment: Had to make some edits as this is for a classified environment. See original post now.

Comment: Why are you using the style tag? Add a class to them, and that will make the code 104% more readable.

Comment: You are trying to show an image from the local harddisk(C:\Users\Public\Pictures\download.jpg). That is newer going to work if the document is served by a webserver due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

The image path you are specifying in the HTML is on your local PC "C:/.." , for it to work you need to enter the path of the image hosted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Also the src atribute value might need to have double quotemarks, like this:

```
<img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\download.jpg" alt="CMB Logo" height="300">
```

And C: drive is on your PC so you might be able to see on a browser on your PC however as mention in the previous post, the src attribute can be a link to an image on a server, for example:

```
<img src="https://some.server.somewhere.com/image.jpg" alt="CMB Logo" height="300">
```